# RegEx to get numbers between periods in IP address?

Tags: regex

Say you have an IP address: 74.125.45.100 so its A.B.C.D

Is there a way to use RegEx to get A,B,C separately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is just to extract the numbers from the IP and not to validate the IP address then you could just do:

```
[0-9]
```

However, I think a simple `String.Split(".")` would be an easier option.

Comment: +1 for suggesting String.Split, because using a regex for this is silly, unless you're trying to *find* an ip address in a longer string.

Comment: +1 for String.Split, it sounds like a lot healthier solution that building a state machine (which regex is).

Comment: It's definately easier, the only caveat would be if the IPs appear at arbitrary positions in a text body.

Answer (score 7):

Something very simple yet ugly would work.. giving you four groups one for each octet.

```
(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})
```

Answer (score 6):

> ([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+).([0-9]+)

...should do it. It's no validating regex though, allows numbers beyond 255 for each part.

Here's a crazy validating one:

> \b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b

Credit to last regex goes to RegexBuddy makers.

Comment: So maybe ([0-9][0-9][0-9]).([0-9][0-9][0-9]).([0-9][0-9][0-9]).([0-9][0-9][0-9])\  :)

Comment: @amischiefr, that would accept 000-999, while the one Skurmedel provided only accepts 000-255, the later being a correctly formatted ip address.

Answer (score 4):

```
/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/
```

Comment: From the above your regex parser should return parameters 1, 2, 3 and 4 which can then be processed separately.

Comment: Note this won't validate an IP address (it'd accept 111111111111.1.000000000000.1234567890) but you didn't ask for that so it's probably okay!

Comment: Each bracketed section '()' returns a value from the regex

Comment: /([012]\d{,2})\.([012]\d{,2})\.([012]\d{,2})\.([012]\d{,2})/ ?

Comment: The question only asked to extract the values, not to validate the syntax. :)

Answer (score 2):

First port of call for regex... [RegEx Library](http://www.regexlib.com)

Answer (score 1):

While others have pointed out various good regexps; May I ask why you absolutely *must* use regular expressions for that? It will be slow and error-prone. Most platforms do have integrated IP address functionality, or provide a way to call to `inet_aton`.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs a validating RegEx for (all possible) IPv4 addresses:

```
([^\d.]|^)([01]{0,1}\d{1,2}|2[0-5][0-5])[.]([01]{0,1}\d{1,2}|2[0-5][0-5])[.]([01]{0,1}\d{1,2}|2[0-5][0-5])[.]([01]{0,1}\d{1,2}|2[0-5][0-5])([^\d]|$)
```

The IP is contained in 2nd, 3rd and 4th parameters. 1st and last are not used. Those are necessary otherwise a wrong IP like:

```
999.1.2.3
```

would be catched as "99.1.2.3". I am not sure if you want to allow IP ending with a dot, e.g.

```
1.2.3.4.
```

If not, change the last part to ([^\d.]|$). I do not allow any dots in front of it though.

I still think this RegEx is a messed monster :) and a better solution would be to validate by hand using a function.